# Download files from S3 using terraform locally

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to download files from `s3` bucket to the server in which i am running `terraform`, is this possible? i tried the below code

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_objects" "my_objects" {
  bucket = "examplebucket"
}

data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object_info" {
  key    = "${element(data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_objects.keys, count.index)}"
  bucket = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_objects.bucket}"

}
provisioner "local-exec" {
    content = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.object_info.body}"
 }
```

When i run `terraform plan` i am getting the below error

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on s3.tf line 11:
  11: provisioner "local-exec" {

Blocks of type "provisioner" are not expected here.
```

Am i missing something here? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `local` [provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/r/file.html)

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_objects" "my_objects" {
  bucket = "examplebucket"
  //prefix = "your_prefix"
}    

data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object_info" {
  count  = "${length(data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_objects.keys)}"
  key    = "${element(data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_objects.keys, count.index)}"
  bucket = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_objects.bucket}"

}

resource "local_file" "foo" {
    count    = "${length(data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_objects.keys)}"
    content  = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.object_info[count.index].body}"
    filename = "/path/to/file-${count.index}"
}
```

PS: make sure your objects have a [human-readable `Content-Type`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/s3_bucket_object.html), the `body` field is available only for such objects.

Comment: thanks for the reply, getting the below error
`Error: Missing resource instance key

  on s3.tf line 12, in resource "local_file" "foo":
  12:     content  = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.object_info.body}"

Because data.aws_s3_bucket_object.object_info has "count" set, its attributes
must be accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    data.aws_s3_bucket_object.object_info[count.index]`

Comment: @doc_noob, fixed the answer

Comment: thanks, i did a `plan` and it worked, can you please tell me how can i access a specific folder inside a `bucket` . ex: `/bucket/folder1/newfiles/`

Comment: use the `prefix` argument for the `aws_s3_bucket_objects`
 resource https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/s3_bucket_objects.html

Comment: When i give `prefix` like this `prefix = "/folder1/newfiles"`, it is showing up below `warning` 
`Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

  on s3.tf line 24, in resource "local_file" "foo":
  24:     count    = "${length(data.aws_s3_bucket_objects.my_objects.keys)}"`

Comment: hi, the code creates file names with ` 0 1 2 3 4 5` instead of downloading files

Comment: @doc_noob, make sure your objects have a human-readable `Content-Type`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212884/discussion-between-dmkvl-and-doc-noob).

Answer (score 0):

`provisioner "local-exec"` must be inside some resource, and there is no argument `content` for it. You might execute some command line or a custom scripts there only.
See the domumentation https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html#example-usage